# CSS alignment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a registration process where the user must accept the TOS before providing Name and Password.

Here is the screen cast and you will see the issue I am having:

http://screencast.com/t/3MF5LSIab (11 secs)

When the user clicks on next after agreeing to the TOS, the div slides out of screen but the next div slides in under the first div and when the first div is gone, the second dive popups up to the top.

*EDIT* - Add missing code

jQuery:

```
$('#tandc_next').click(function(){
    $('#tandc').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    $('#account_info').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

CSS for both divs:

```
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #999;
color: #000;
padding: 8px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

And the parent container has this:

```
.registration form > div {
    position: relative; }
```

The html layout is:

```
div.registration
     form
        div#tandc
        div#account_info
```

How do I make it so that the 2nd div slides in so that they top of each div is at the same height?

Comment: Do you have some code to post? Do you `float:left` right now?

Comment: some **css** would be very helpful ..., what `position:` do you use ? (try `fixed` or `absolute`)

Comment: Yikes. Sorry about missing the code. :( I've edited the original to add it.

Comment: May be worth adding more tags to this question, as I think it's not just a CSS issue. At least add Javascript (and is that jQuery I see?).

Comment: icabod, yes, it is jQuery. I think I've added all the relavent code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
.registration form > div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
   }
```

This way, they both will be aligned on the top of their parent.

**EDIT:** the problem is that jQuery uses a wrapper to slide, to overcome such effect, you'll have to wrap them in outer div that will be positioned.

An example of the following could be achieved like that : http://jsfiddle.net/HKsHy/

Using the following layout

```
div.registration
   form
      div
         div
      div
         div
```

And adding the css from above (the one with the absolute positioning)

And using the following jQuery

```
$(".registration form > div").has("#account_info").css("display","none");

$('#tandc_next').click(function() {
    $('#tandc').hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    $(".registration form > div").has("#account_info").css("display","block");
    $('#account_info').show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
```

The first line has to be executed to hide the second div. It's then showed back. during the slide.

**EDIT2**:

You could even achieve a cleaner show effect using a timeout. Like that:

```
function showSecond(){
    $(".registration form > div").has("#account_info").show();
    $('#account_info').show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);   
}
$('#tandc_next').click(function() {
    $('#tandc').hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(showSecond,500);       

});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HKsHy/1/

Comment: py,they are aligned to the top of the page and it still doesn't solve the issue. When the 2nd div slides in, it is on the bottom until the 1st disappears.

Comment: Ah ok, i didn't get that part.

Comment: What's your version of jQuery? Because it's implemented in 1.4. You can upgrade or try using the following: $(".registration form > div:has(#account_info)"). It was implemented earlier if the doc is right.